# How to fix 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type 'passages' because requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, lucene.net

I am trying to read and access a large JSON file from local directory using newtonsoft.json in c# but always gave me the error. I created two classes for accessing it.
This is my example JSON data:

```
{
    "passages": [
        {
            "passage_text": "xxxxxxx",
            "url": "xxxxx",
        }
    ]
    "answer":"xxxxxx",
    "query_id":"Xxxxx"
}
```

here is the code I have tried:

```cs
public class collection
{
    public passages passages { get; set; }
    public String answers { get; set; }
    public String query_id { get; set; }
}

public class passages
{
    public String url { get; set; }
    public String passage_text { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the part I tried to read and access to JSON file:

```cs
String jsonPath = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\647\project\collection\sample_collection.json"  ;
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(jsonPath);
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        collection c = serializer.Deserialize<collection>(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(c.passages.url);
     }
}
```

And it gave me this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'LuceneIndexApplication.passages' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '[0].passages', line 1, position 15.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to map passages to from an array into a list.

so all that you should need to change is:

```
public class collection
    {
        public passages passages { get; set; }
        public String answers { get; set; }
        public String query_id { get; set; }
    }
```

should be

```
public class collection
    {
        public List<passages> passages { get; set; }
        public String answers { get; set; }
        public String query_id { get; set; }
    }
```

note the List in the latter.